# Method not applicable for the arguments, possible Exception type erasure issue?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, hamcrest

I'm using Java8 and am trying to write a test helper that will validate the exception thrown is of a specific type. Here's an initial version that works:

```
private static <E extends Exception> void expectThrow(Callable<Void> callable, Class<E> exceptionClass) {
    try {
        callable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertTrue(exceptionClass.isInstance(e));
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is replace the catch block with a hamcrest matcher so I get more useful info from failures:

```
        assertThat(e, Matchers.isA(exceptionClass));
```

but this doesn't compile - I get this lovely error: `The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (Exception, Matcher<E>)`

This puzzles me - shouldn't this work? This seems similar to the following case, which works perfectly fine:

```
    Integer a = 3;
    assertThat(a, Matchers.isA(Number.class));
```

After playing around somewhat, the following also works:

```
        assertThat((E)e, Matchers.isA(exceptionClass));
```

Though that gives me a helpful "unchecked cast from Exception to E" type safety warning.  I know I can't `catch (E e)` - type erasure and all...

What's going on? How can I update my test helper in a nice typesafe way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [long-standing issue](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/27) finally fixed 5 days ago. The signature for `isA` was broken. Until the next release of Hamcrest makes the fix available, and until your project is using that release, you'll have to use

```
assertThat(e, is(instanceOf(exceptionClass)))
```

Comment: Daaaang... that's kinda funny it stuck around for that long!